# Polar form (Modulus & Argument)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

**Questions:**

a) Express $-4i$ in polar form

b) Hence solve the equation $z^2 =-4i$

---

I've attempted the question and was only able to find $z=4$ using the form $r(\cos x+i\sin x)=z$.

Could someone please show me or explain how to do step by step?

Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you familiar with Argand diagrams, if so I recommend making a quick sketch.

We use the relation $$z=(x+iy)=r\left(\cos(\theta)+i\sin (\theta)\right)$$
$|4i|=4$. This is the magnitude of the complex vector

$\arg(z)=\tan^{-1}\left(\cfrac{y}{x}\right)$. In your case $x=0$ and $y=-4$.

$\arg(-4i)=\tan^{-1}\left(\cfrac{-4}{0}\right)=\tan^{-1}(-\infty)=-\cfrac{\pi}{2}=\theta$. This is the angle the complex vector makes with the real-axis on an Argand diagram. Obviously taking the inverse tan of infinity is not the best way to do it as $\infty$ is undefined so making a sketch on an Argand Diagram makes more sense.

So $-4i=4(\cos(-\frac{\pi}{2})+i\sin (-\frac{\pi}{2}))=-4i$

Now that we know the argument and magnitude we can move on to solve part b)

First rewrite $z^2 =-4i$ as $z^2 +4i =0$ and this time $\arg(z^2)=2k\pi-\cfrac{\pi}{2}$ as any integer $k$ of $2\pi$ yields the same result. Then one way of finding the solutions is to use $$z^n=(x+iy)^n=r^ne^{in\theta}=r\left(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin (n\theta)\right)$$ which is known as De Moivres Theorem. But if you have not come across this it might be best to look it up. So we have 
$$z=r^{\frac{1}{n}}\left(\cos(\theta)+i\sin (\theta)\right)^\frac{1}{n}=
4^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\cos(-\cfrac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)+i\sin (-\cfrac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)\right)^\frac{1}{2}=
2\left(\cos\left(\cfrac{-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi}{2}\right)+i\sin \left(\cfrac{-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi}{2}\right)\right)$$ and this is valid for $k=0$ and $k=1$ as there are two roots to the equation. So now you simply substitute these values of $k$ into the formula to get the two solutions. After you've done that you should get answers of $z=\sqrt2-\sqrt2i$ and $z=\sqrt2i-\sqrt2$. I have omitted the simplification steps that lead to these results for $z$ as it takes up too much space (and time). But I can show you if you like.

It's helpful to notice that $z^2=(\sqrt2-\sqrt2i)(\sqrt2i-\sqrt2)= 2i -2 -2i^2+2i=2i -2+2+2i=4i$ which is precisely what we would expect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Blaze, could you explain how you got the π/2 for the  θ?

Comment: @Red I'll explain further in my answer

Comment: I'm stil abit confused about the pi/2, I do understand that -4/0 is undefined although after that im clueless in how you got to pi/2. @BLAZE

Comment: @RedQueen10101 I found $-\cfrac{\pi}{2}$ instantly by making a sketch on an Argand diagram, have you come across these? Otherwise if you look at $\tan\theta$ graph there is a vartical asymptote at $y=-\infty$ at this point $x=-\cfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I can confirm that your answer is correct, although my logics keeps point to the fact that the angle is 3π/2 as x=0 and y=-4. Yes I have seen argrand diagrams

Comment: @RedQueen10101 Okay no problem, use your computer to bring up a graph of $\tan\theta$ you will see why it must be $-\cfrac{\pi}{2}$ in no time.

Comment: are -pi/2 the same as 3pi/2 in this case? Okay ill take a look at the graph--> Oh okay yes I do understand it now, although how would this be shown on a argrand diagram im curious?

Comment: @RedQueen10101 At $\cfrac{3\pi}{2}$. the value of $\tan\theta$ is $+\infty$ so they are not the same

Comment: Yes i understand it now. Could you please start me off for b?

Comment: yes I've used De Moives theorem just not too familar with it